# When using Jira, how do I ensure each team member has enough work in a sprint?

Tags: project-management, agile, jira, scrum, greenhopper

While doing planning sessions using Rapid Board what are some reasonable ways to make sure each person on the team has a decent enough amount of work for the length of the sprint?

e.g. if you have 10 people on the team, how can you quickly see if 1 person only has 2 hours worth of work? Are you supposed to wait for them to speak up or can this be done through Greenhopper somehow?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about project management, not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to make sure that everybody has work to do throughout the sprint, is to let them sign up for work every time they complete the previous task. This means that the members will be "pulling" work, rather than having their work "pushed" onto them.

If you conduct a daily scrum - daily - you will find out pretty quickly that someone is not signing up for new work - that he's either stuck on what he has, or not picking new work. Essentially, if you break up your work into small enough tasks, you will know what is going on within a day.

All this will work for you regardless of which software tool you use to track your sprint.

Comment: I believe that misses the point of scrum, in scrum you're committing to a set amount of work for the sprint period. It's not a variable amount (ideally)

Comment: It doesn't really. On the contrary. The *team* commits to a set amount of work that the *whole* team will deliver. This is not the same as each member committing to *their own* work. What you may be missing about Scrum, is that you should *avoid* the local optimization that tracking individual commitments will cause. Having the whole team work as one *is* what Scrum is all about. At least it is _one_ thing.

Comment: ah, that makes more sense then. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jira, (and your project can afford it) I would suggest looking into the add-on "Green Hopper." It is also made by Atlassian and does a lot of what you are asking for. You can view individuals and see how much work they have as well as how much free time is remaining.

You can also drag the stories (Jira issues represented as virtual index cards) into different iterations (sprints) and onto different people. As well, it will help you to run your daily standup (using it as the scrum board), however YMMV.

m